# iPhone web app freezes after incoming call is declined. Why? What can be done?

Tags: jquery, iphone, web-applications, ios

After an incoming call is declined, the iPhone web app that I've developed completely becomes unresponsive. The app is written in HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, and jQTouch.

If the call is accepted, then the app restarts after the call ends. I’ve read that it is normal for iOS to terminate your app when a call is accepted. (I do not know if the expected behavior is for iOS to return the user to the iPhone home page or perhaps to kick off the web app again.)

I doubt, though, that it is normal for the app to freeze if the call is declined.

Does anyone know what to do about this?

Is there even a way that my web app can know that a call is coming in and take action accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Does your web app become responsive after several seconds or is full page refresh the only solution no matter how long you wait? If it's only frozen for a few seconds, I think there might be a lot of JavaScript operations queuing up while the phone is ringing. After you decline the call, Mobile Safari is busy working on those operations.